# wifi doesn't work on 1 of 5 Raspberry Pi 3 with the same image

Tags: wifi

I have five Raspberry Pi 3 working with the same image. Only on one the buildin wifi did not work. With an usb wifi and the same wpa settings all is fine. I already did rpi-update and uname -a gives

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.54-v7+ #1041 SMP Tue Oct 10 14:22:12 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

output from lsusb as suggested by @GAD3R:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 
802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 
Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is the buildin wifi just broken or are there other possible explanations?

Comment: Just to exclude this possibility, are they all powered by the same means?

Comment: yes, this happens also when the raspi uses the same power supply.

Comment: Please spell out Raspberry Pi!

Comment: Welcome . Please edit your question by adding the output of `lsusb` .